# Input button active styling? (without anchors)

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on making some stylish buttons using as basic of HTML as possible.

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

However, styling the "pressed down" state is proving difficult. Everywhere I look online, designers seem to bypass this problem by using anchors, and then taking advantage of CSS's `:active` pseudo-class. Unfortunately, it appears buttons do not have this. They have `:focus`, but that doesn't really work the same way.

**So my question is this:** Is it possible to style a "down" state without modifying this HTML? I am willing to use jQuery if necessary, but I'm mostly hoping that there is a pure CSS solution that doesn't involve anchors. What do you all recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Which browsers are the :active state not working for you? This really ugly button's active state works in Safari, Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/85BKk/

Comment: Oh man! It turns out you're all right--the `:active` pseudo-class *does* work! It turns out that the reason it wasn't working for me was because I had my CSS alphabetized, so my `:hover` rules were overwriting the `:active` ones. Thanks for the help, all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can apply the `:active` pseudo-class to **form buttons**.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xvWG5/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
input:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

this works for me in Firefox, Chrome and IE9

Answer (score 0):

What kind of styling are you trying to achieve? I can see font colour of elements in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/eb6eU/) change to red when pressed down in Safari6 and FF12.

[W3 suggests there may be cross-browser inconsistencies](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/C15.html) in supporting dynamic pseudo-classes and handling certain properties; you'll need to provide sample code you're having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the option to use the  tag? I think you'll find it's infinitely more flexible. For example, the :active state does appear to work for me in Safari, Chrome & Firefox (I do not have access to IE at the moment):

```
button {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    border: 0;
}

button:active {
    background-color: blue;
}
​
```